# can't install teamviewer in ubuntu13.04 amd64 i386

Tags: teamviewer

problem,

```
dpkg: error processing teamviewer_linux_x64.deb (--install):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

You installed a 32 bit `ubuntu 13.04` os.But the downloaded teamviewer package is for 64bit ubuntu os.so please download `32 bit(i386)version` of teamviewer package and install it.